# How can i create a method type bool and loop over controls to decide on cases?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private bool LoopOverControls(bool reset, bool checkIfEmpty)
        {
            bool results;
            foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
            {
                if ((ctrl as TextBox) != null)
                {
                    if (reset == true)
                        (ctrl as TextBox).Text = "";
                    if (checkIfEmpty == true)
                        results = true;
                }
            }
            return results;
        }
```

I want to use the method in some places in the code. Instead making loop over the controls over again each time i want to make a method i can call.

The method was before:

```
private void LoopOvercontrols(bool reset, bool checkIfEmpty)
        {
            foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
            {
                if ((ctrl as TextBox) != null)
                {
                    if (reset == true)
                        (ctrl as TextBox).Text = "";
                    if (checkIfEmpty == true)

                }
            }
        }
```

And this is the places i'm using the loop over the controls in my code the first place is in the constructor: I check if the textBoxes are not empty then do something in this case change btnReset enable true.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
            {
                if ((ctrl as TextBox) != null)
                {
                    (ctrl as TextBox).TextChanged += on_TextChanged;
                    if ((ctrl as TextBox).Text != "")
                    {
                        btnReset.Enabled = true;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Then inside another event this time i check if the textboxes are empty and set the btnReset enable to false:

```
foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls)
            {
                if ((ctrl as TextBox) != null)
                {
                    (ctrl as TextBox).TextChanged += on_TextChanged;
                    if ((ctrl as TextBox).Text == "")
                    {
                        btnReset.Enabled = false;
                    }
                }
            }
```

So far i'm looping over the textBoxes in two places but i might want to loop over them again later in other places. The problem is how to make the method LoopOverControls so i can decide with a bool and maybe other properties some cases and using buttons or other controls within the decitions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write a method that receive the action to be executed as parameter.
The work for this new method is to enumerate all the textboxes and call the action method for each one.

```
public void TextBoxEnumerateAndAction(Action<TextBox> execute)
{
    // Get just the TextBoxes, no need of ugly casts...
    foreach(TextBox t in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
    {
        execute?.Invoke(t);
        // This part is common to every textbox, so it can stay inside the
        // enumeration loop....
        btnReset.Enabled = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text)
    }
}
```

Now define the Action methods to pass to TextBoxEnumerateAndAction

```
void AddTextChangedHandler(TextBox t)
{
     t.TextChanged += on_TextChanged;
}
void RemoveTextChangedHandler(TextBox t)
{
     t.TextChanged -= on_TextChanged;
}
```

So, everywhere you need to add or remove the TextChanged handler you could call

```
TextBoxEnumerateAndAction(AddTextChangedHandler);
```

Or if you have more fancy situations, you could simply define another action to pass to TextBoxEnumerateAndAction

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you just add some comfort methods to contain the looping and type selection logic and allow callers to pass in delegate function to control the applied logic.

for example:

```
public void ActOn<TControl>(Action<TControl> applyFunction)
    where TControl : Control
{
    if (applyFunction == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(applyFunction)); }
    var controlsOfChosenType = this
        .Controls
        .OfType<TControl>();
    foreach (var control in controlsOfChosenType)
    {
        applyFunction(control);
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
ActOn<TextBox>(textbox => textbox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString());
```